# The sequence $a_n=n(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{1}{k})^{1/n}$ is bounded and converges to a non zero limit (True or False).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I thought $a_n=n(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{1}{k})^{1/n}$ is unbounded, since $\sin\frac{1}{k}$ is bounded and when multiplied with $n$........ What's wrong here? The answer is convergent and it converges to $e$ (True). Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $1-\epsilon <\frac {\sin x} x <1+\epsilon$ for $x>0$ sufficiently small. Use Stirling's Formula.

Comment: This is amazing @geetha290krm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\ln a_n=\ln n+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\sin\frac{1}{k})
=\ln n+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\frac{1}{k})-
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\ln(\sin\frac{1}{k})-\ln(\frac{1}{k})) \\
=\ln n+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\frac{1}{k})-
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(k\sin\frac{1}{k}).
$$
Clearly, $n\sin(1/n)\to 1$, hence $\ln(n\sin(1/n))\to 0$ and thus
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(k\sin\frac{1}{k})\to 0$.

Meanwhile
$$
\ln n+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\frac{1}{k})=
-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\frac{k}{n}).
$$
But
$$
-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\frac{k}{n})\to-\int_0^1\ln x\,dx=-x\ln x+x\,\Big|_0^1=1.
$$
Thus $\ln a_n\to 1$ and finally $a_n\to e$.

Note. One may also use the following Lemma:

If $b_n>0$ and $b_{n+1}/b_n\to \ell$, then $b_n^{1/n}\to \ell$.

Then for $b_n=n^n\prod_{k=1}^n \sin(1/k)$ we have
$$
\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} \sin(1/k)}{n^n\prod_{k=1}^n \sin(1/k)}=(n+1)\sin(1/(n+1)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to e,
$$
and hence
$$
a_n=b_n^{1/n}\to e.
$$

Answer (score 4):

You can use Stolz's theorem to get the limit. In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln a_n&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\ln n+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\sin\frac{1}{k})\bigg]\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\ln n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\sin\frac{1}{k})}{n}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\bigg[(n+1)\ln (n+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\ln(\sin\frac{1}{k})\bigg]-\bigg[n\ln n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(\sin\frac{1}{k})\bigg]}{(n+1)-n}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[(n+1)\ln (n+1)-n\ln n+\ln(\sin\frac{1}{n+1})\bigg]\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[(n+1)\ln (n+1)-n\ln n-\ln(n+1)+\ln((n+1)\sin\frac{1}{n+1})\bigg]\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[n\ln (\frac{n+1}{n})+\ln((n+1)\sin\frac{1}{n+1})\bigg]\\
&=&1
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=e. $$

Comment: Nice use of Stolz's theorem  $(\to +1)$

Answer (score 2):

Starting from @xpaul's answer
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \log (a_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty } \,\Bigg[(n+1) \log (n+1)-n \log (n)+\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right) \Bigg]$$ Expanding as a series for large $n$
$$(n+1) \log (n+1)-n \log (n)+\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right)=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{6 n^2}+\frac{1}{12 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$a_n=e-\frac{e}{2 n}+\frac{7 e}{24 n^2}-\frac{e}{48
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Computing
$$a_{100}=2.625\cdots$$ while the truncated series gives
$\frac{47761399}{48000000}e=2.705\cdots$

$$a_{1000}=2.706\cdots$$ while the truncated series gives
$\frac{47976013999 }{48000000000}e=2.717\cdots$

**Edit**

If we want to go further, we could write
$$\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)=-\log(k)-\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1}\, \frac{ 2^{2 m-1}\,\, B_{2 m}}{m \,(2 m)!}\,\, k^{-2 m}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach.
$$ \frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)\tag{Weierstrass 1} $$
$$ \log\sin x-\log x = \sum_{n\geq 1}\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)=O(x^2)\tag{2}$$
$$ \log\sin\frac{1}{k} = -\log k + O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\tag{3} $$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\sin\frac{1}{k} = -\log(n!) + O(1)=-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(n)+n+O(1)\tag{Stirling 4} $$
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\sin\frac{1}{k} = -\log(n)+1+o(1)\tag{5} $$
$$ \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/n}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\sin\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{e}{n}\left(1+o(1)\right)\tag{6} $$
$$ n\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/n} = \color{red}{e+o(1)}.\tag{7}$$